# Which GUI Library does Microsoft use for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, dll

I am currently looking for a good C++ GUI Lib for Windows and thought I will pick one where I can see how powerfull it is (I dont like qt..).

So is Visual Studio itself programmed with win32/MFC or did they createt another GUI Lib for this (and similar) purposes? If yes which did they used?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio uses [Windows Presentation Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/aa970268(v=vs.100)). With some old parts remaining in Windows GDI.